# Select rows until running sum reaches specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I have the following data:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (usr VARCHAR(100), dt DATE, amount INT);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('a', '2018-01-01', 100), -- 100
('a', '2018-02-01', 100), -- 200
('a', '2018-03-01', 100), -- 300
('a', '2018-04-01', 100), -- 400
('a', '2018-05-01', 100), -- 500
('b', '2018-01-01', 150), -- 150
('b', '2018-02-01', 150), -- 300
('b', '2018-03-01', 150), -- 450
('b', '2018-04-01', 150), -- 600
('b', '2018-05-01', 150); -- 750
```

And a value such as 300 or 301 (a user variable or column). I want to select rows until running total of amount reaches the specified value, with the following twist:

- For 300 I want to select first 3 rows for a and first 2 rows for b
- For 301 I want to select first 4 rows for a and first 3 rows for b

This is supposed to be simple but the solutions I found do not handle the second case.

Comment: how does amount go from 100 to 150? how did you get 300/301? the details is missing.

Comment: Is `amount` guaranteed to be non negative? i.e. the running total can never fall?

Comment: @MartinSmith interesting. Assume it is always positive but bonus if it handles negative values too.

Comment: You need to define how that should be handled. It should just return all rows until the running total first reaches 300 or subsequent rows too if the total drops below that again

Comment: @MartinSmith assume that it is greedy i.e. selects as many rows as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (usr VARCHAR(100), dt DATE, amount INT);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('a', '2018-01-01', 100), -- 100
('a', '2018-02-01', 100), -- 200
('a', '2018-03-01', 100), -- 300
('a', '2018-04-01', 100), -- 400
('a', '2018-05-01', 100), -- 500
('b', '2018-01-01', 150), -- 150
('b', '2018-02-01', 150), -- 300
('b', '2018-03-01', 150), -- 450
('b', '2018-04-01', 150), -- 600
('b', '2018-05-01', 150); -- 750

DECLARE @Total INT = 301;

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY usr ORDER BY dt) AS RunTotal
    FROM @t
)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  cte.RunTotal - cte.amount < @Total -- running total for previous row is less
                                          -- than @Total then include current row
```

Comment: i am getting an exception near order by dt

Comment: Runs fine for me on SQL Server 2017 Express (14.0.1000.169) - what version are you on? I think window functions (`OVER`) were added in SQL 2008, so perhaps if you're on a very old version, you might not be able to use them?

Comment: @3N1GM4  i am on ssms 2017

Comment: @Amitchauhan - Using SSMS 2017 doesn't mean the underlying database engine is that version. What result do you get if you run `select @@version`?

Comment: @3N1GM4 its Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) - may be this is the reason i am getting the exception

Comment: Yeah, I just double checked and this functionality was fully added in SQL 2012, so that's likely the reason you're having the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (usr VARCHAR(100), dt DATE, amount INT);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('a', '2018-01-01', 100), -- 100
('a', '2018-02-01', 100), -- 200
('a', '2018-03-01', 100), -- 300
('a', '2018-04-01', 100), -- 400
('a', '2018-05-01', 100), -- 500
('b', '2018-01-01', 150), -- 150
('b', '2018-02-01', 150), -- 300
('b', '2018-03-01', 150), -- 450
('b', '2018-04-01', 150), -- 600
('b', '2018-05-01', 150); -- 750

declare @target int = 300;

with cte_RunningTotal as
(
    select  
        usr,
        dt,
        amount,
        sum(amount) over (partition by usr order by dt rows unbounded preceding) as runningTotal
    from @t 
)
select *
from cte_RunningTotal 
where runningTotal < @target + amount
order by usr, dt
```